# How to find the position for an element in a li with jquery or vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets imagine I have the following HTML code.

I need to find the position within the LI elements for the LI which has the class focus applied.

In this example the result should be 2 (if at 0 index). Any idea how to do it?

```
<ul class="mylist">
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li class="focus">Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Cherniv you mean `index`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't know about `index` in VanillaJS

Comment: I know, I was being facetious in the fact that `index` in jQuery makes this a 1-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.index()`

```
var index = $('.focus').index();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YPAn/)

**Specific list**

```
$('.mylist .focus').index()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YPAn/1/)

Comment: thanks it works, I have made a little change $('ul > li.focus').index();

Comment: how can I consider also for a specific list like with class mylist?

Comment: You could do it like this `$('.mylist .focus').index()`

Answer (score 4):

In pure JavaScript:

```
var index = 0;
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var len = lis.length; index < len; ++index) {
    if (lis[index].className.match(/\bfocus\b/)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nAKZF/)

Answer (score 3):

While you've already accepted an answer to your question, I thought I'd put together a simple `index()` method for `HTMLElement`s:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.index = function () {
    var self = this,
        parent = self.parentNode,
        i = 0;
    while (self.previousElementSibling){
        i++;
        self = self.previousElementSibling
    }
    return this === parent.children[i] ? i : -1;
}

var focus = document.querySelector('li.focus'),
    i = focus.index();
console.log(i); // 2
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qf63s/).

References:

- [`Element.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementTraversal.previousElementSibling)
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you should be able to get it, via `index`. With classes, you could run into issues, when having multiple of them.

I prepared a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpzQsawgaKV3d97lVL5V?p=preview), where you can see a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the expanded version (jquery) would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li').each(function(){
  var cls=$(this).attr('class');
  if(cls=='focus'){
   alert($(this).index());
  }
 });
});
```